# when are dependant classes beeing loaded

Tags: java, classloader

Let's say I have a class:

```java
public class SomeClass {

  public NotPresent1 method1(NotPresent2 input) {return null;}

  public void method2() {}

}
```

I compiled this class but on runtime, NotPresent1 and/or NotPresent2 are not on the classpath. can i load that class? can i instantiate such class and call `method2()`? or maybe i can even call `method1(null)`?

Comment: This question, as asked, can be ***trivially*** answered by just running the experiment. The more interesting question, which you didn't ask, is **why** you can create a `SomeClass` instance and call `method1(null)` successfully.

Comment: now, i'm lost. you said i can't load such class and now you are saying i can instantiate it

Comment: @ piotrek: I was wrong, which is why I deleted the answer. I ran the experiment and was shocked to find that not only could I instantiate `SomeClass` instances, I could call `method1(null)`. Even now I'm pouring through [JLS §12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html) trying to figure out why I don't get a resolution error. Sadly, though, I have work to do (even though it's Sunday) and so I can't spend more time on it... I *think* it's because the code never refers to a non-constant static field on `NotPresent1` or `NotPresent2` and we never try to instantiate them.

Comment: i see. i started to read your link [jls 12.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.3) and it states "an implementation **may choose to** resolve each symbolic reference in a class". but i'm not sure if that's exactly what we are talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it is not specified/depends on VM/JIT implementation. I know that the current VM loads classes lazy, as late as possible (when code of that class is invoked/state accessed). This was done ~1.3 or so in order to speed up startup time of Fat Clients (Swing). However it may happen that an agressive optimizing JIT loads them in advance (e.g. to optimize server side performance).
Don't rely on current behaviour regarding class loading timing.